# Property "FullName" cannot be found on the object for Get-VisualStudioTemplate

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019

When I run the "Get-VisualStudioTemplate" command in a NuGet Powershell window in Visual Studio 2019, I'm getting an error that property "FullName" cannot be found on the object. I'm attempting to get the "EmptyWebApplicationProject40.vstemplate" in the C# format. I confirmed the template name was correct in the default template set, so I'm not sure where this error would be coming from.

Comment: Is your script using Strict Mode? Unfortunately, some cmdlets aren’t compatible with that enabled and fail with errors like the one you’ve seen.

Comment: Thank you, that might do the trick. I'm invoking someone else's PSM1 file, and I see "Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0" at the top of the file. I'll see about commenting that out and check if it works, and update the original author if so. Cheers!

Comment: Cool. You can always disable strict mode just before the call to Get-VisualStudioTemplate and re-enable it afterwards if you don’t want to disable it for the entire script. Strict mode is often a life saver, so it’s better to leave it enabled if you can...